# Cloudwatch Percentile with SEARCH

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

I am using SEARCH as for my metric in AWS CDK. Here is the code:

```
dashboard.add_widgets(
  cw.GraphWidget(
  title='My Fancy Widget',
  left=[
     "SEARCH('{AWS/EC2,InstanceId} MetricName=ResponseTime', 'Average')"
  ],
  width=12,
)
```

I'd like to have percentiles on the ResponseTime metric. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer. Here is the list of functions we can pass:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Statistics-definitions.html

For my case I should have used `p95` instead of `Average`. Certainly I can add more SEARCH metrics to add other percentiles.